# How do I get my webpage go to another page when the validations are true

Tags: javascript, window.location

I need help trying to get my webpage to go to a thank you page if all validation are true and entered correctly then it would go there. But I have no luck trying to get it to work. If there is any way that I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this code from your codepen validates before submit.

```js
if (isValid == true) {
    $("registration_form").submit();
}
```

You have to add:

```js
if (isValid == true) {
    $("registration_form").submit();
    window.location.replace("http://example.com/ok.php");
}
```